# Is it accurate to say that C++ is a partially type safe language?

Tags: c++

There are some features in C++ that are type safe and some other features that are not.

Example of C++ type safety:

```
char c = 'a';
int *p = &c;    // this is not allowed (compiler error)
```

Example of C++ lack of type safety:

```
int *p;        // I don't have to initialize p, and so it will have some junk/random value
*p = 12345;    // this will probably lead to segmentation fault!
```

I have read in a couple of articles that C++ is not a type safe language. Can I consider it to be a non type safe language, or is it more accurate to say that it is a partially type safe language?

Comment: I would say your second example doesn't have anything to do with type safety.

Comment: That's just plain old undefined behaviour.

Comment: C++ is a type safe language, don't mix concepts. Type safety involves types, dereferencing an invalid pointer has nothing to do with types.

Comment: @Hurkyl if in my second example, I assigned `p` an `int` value (for example: `int *p = 12345`) and the compiler allowed it, is this considered a violation of type safety?

Comment: @Tom The thing is, you never said it's an `int`. It is just a decimal integer number that can be of any type.

Comment: @Tom in that case 12345 is a memory address location and is fine as long as your target system actually has memory at that location that is aligned to hold an int.  If an int is 2 or 4 bytes it is not properly aligned and is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Second example is type safe. The compiler's type system only allows you to screw up your program using the correct type.

Comment: You don't assign anything to `p`, you assign it to `*p` (contents of `p`) which is an `int`.

Comment: @Tim `int *p = 12345;` is a compiler error - invalid coversion from `int` to `int*`. That's not what you do in your question. `int *p; *p = 12345;` is something quite different.

Comment: @Galik Yes, this is not what I do in my question, this is a different question I asked.

Comment: Why we need the same question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39814446/confused-about-the-benefits-of-type-safety

Comment: @Klaus it's not the same question.

Comment: It looks like the same question to me, what is the difference?

Comment: @Galik in this question I am talking about how C++ has some features that are type safe and some other features that are not. In the other question I am talking about how type safety prevents me from accessing memory places I am not allowed to access, but there is another "problem" in C++ that allows me to also access memory places I am not allowed to access (which is uninitialized variables).

Comment: @Tom It looks like the same question to me. You wrap it up in slightly different preamble but then you ask exactly the same question at the end. There is nothing about your example that violates type safety in either of your questions.

Comment: You say "I am allowed to do the behavior that type safety tries to prevent ". But that is a false statement. Writing to uninitialized pointers has nothing whatsoever to do with type safety.

Comment: @Galik let's say that C++ allowed me to assign a `char*` to an `int*` (`int *p = &c;`), now when I dereference p I will access 3 extra bytes that I am not allowed to access (but since type safety prevents me from doing this assignment, then this will not happen). However, when I dereference an uninitialized pointer, then I am accessing memory places that I am not allowed to access (a problem which type safety prevents).

Comment: @Tom Type safety is **not** about checking there is enough memory to store the result. It is about checking that the **bit-wise format** of the memory is compatible. But even if it was about the size of the memory type safety continues to prevent that problem in your uninitialized pointer example. If you had assigned a `new char` to your `int*` then type safety would prevent you from overwriting non-existent memory. If you has assigned a `new int` to your `int*` the type system would correctly ascertain that the target of the pointer references enough memory to contain the result.

Comment: @Tom  So the type checks are still happening and preventing type safety problems. What is **not** being checked is if the pointer has been initialized. If it is initialized then type safety ensures it is initialized with the correct amount of memory to receive the integer. Type safety checks are **not** there to decide whether or not the programmer actually initialized the pointer they are there to ensure that when the pointer is initialized it is initialized with enough memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *reasonable* and *practically meaningful* to say that C++ is a partially type safe language.

C++ started as an extension of original mid- to late 1970's C, which was designed as a kind of high level portable assembly language, to make Unix more portable and easier to maintain. C++ added type safety for its new features, but with the goal of being mainly compatible with C (in particular using all those existing C libraries, including their headers) the original core of C had to be left as it was.

In particular, C++ got the decay of array to pointer from C. In C++ it isn't type safe because it allows an implicit conversion from array of `Derived` to pointer to `Base`, which can in turn be indexed but with Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The example you are giving is not violating "type safety" at all. Here:

> Example of C++ lack of type safety:
>
> ```
> int *p;     // I don't have to initialize p, and so it will have some junk/random value
> *p = 12345; // this will probably lead to segmentation fault!
> ```

In that example `*p` is an `int` and you are assigning it the number `12345` which is **also** an `int`.

The compiler is not allowing you to violate the type system because you are assigning one `int` to another `int`.

The fact that the pointer you are dereferencing to get to one of your `int`s is not initialized is causing a potential crash but it has nothing to do with type safety.

This will not crash:

```
int* p = new int;
*p = 12345;
```

Here you are writing an `int` (`12345`) to another `int` (`*p`) but this time the `int` you are writing to (`*p`) actually exists.

It is **not** type safety that the compiler is failing to check it is the integrity of the pointer.

Comment: I have one more question about type safety if you don't mind, if I have an `int` variable (`int i = 12345`), and then I tried to treat this `int` variable as a function pointer (`i()`), now the compiler will prevent me from doing so of course. Is this prevention because I violated type safety when I tried to treat `i` as a function pointer, or is this does not relate to type safety?

Comment: @Tom Yes that's a type violation. The type determines what operations can be performed on an object.