# Confused about the benefits of type safety

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand what are the benefits of type safety. But I am confused about something.

Based on my understanding of type safety, type safety prevents you from mixing incompatible data types. For example, you cannot assign a `char*` to an `int*`:

```
char c = 'a';
int *p = &c;    // this is not allowed (compiler error)
```

Now I am guessing that the benefit of not allowing such an assignment is because if I tried to dereference `p` I will access 3 extra bytes that I am not allowed to access.

But in C++ I am allowed to do the following:

```
int *p;        // I don't have to initialize p, and so it will have some junk/random value
*p = 12345;    // this will probably lead to segmentation fault!
```

So basically in the last example I am allowed to do the behavior that type safety tries to prevent in the first example! Am I missing something here?!

Comment: Your 2nd example exposes undefined behavior, nothing to do with type safety.

Comment: Your second example de-references an uninitialized pointer.  This is undefined behavior since `p` is pointing to an arbitrary memory location.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Segmentation Fault when attempting to print value in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278085/segmentation-fault-when-attempting-to-print-value-in-c)

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I did not say that my second example is related to type safety.

Comment: Why ask two pretty much equal questions if the first has an answer and related commetns already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39813866/is-it-accurate-to-say-that-c-is-a-partially-type-safe-language

Comment: @stijn these two questions are not the same.

Comment: Nor did I claim they are. But obviously they are related, they even use the same nonsensical samples, and imo the answers and comments on the first one already cover everything - or with a small edit of the first question it would be the same as this one.

Comment: The question shows only that ignoring compiler warnings will also result in broken code:-) Type safety and uninitialized data has really nothing todo with each other.

Comment: Nice to get the same question twice! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39813866/is-it-accurate-to-say-that-c-is-a-partially-type-safe-language

Comment: @Klaus it's not the same question.

Comment: You are missing the fact that you are writing an `int` (`12345`) to an `int` (`*p`), so your expression is completely type safe. The problem has nothing to do with type safety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ is a complex language, designed by many persons over the span of many years thus it's impossible to find a clean and clear design direction.

One of the original ideas was however to not let any room for speed improvement between C++ and assembler so the language in most parts sacrificed safety when this would have implied a performance cost.

The use of a "wrong type" is something done at compile time and has no cost at run-time. Checking for the use of uninitialized variables (or the forbidding uninitialized variables present in most other languages) instead would require a run-time cost penalty and so it has been left out.

Comment: The comment I was replying to has disappeared,

Comment: Why is it hard for the compiler to detect uninitialized variables at compile time, isn't it already doing it and displaying a warning?!

Comment: Yes, it can detect this, and issue a warning - I was surprised it was just a warning but apparently the C++11 standards don't require an error to be raised in this case. However just treat all warnings as "errors" - they are alerting you to suspicious code.

Comment: @Tom: the detection of use of uninitialized variables is a difficult problem to solve in general (halt-difficult I'd say). What compilers do is complaining about the use of "possibly" uninitialized variables... very often useful but sometimes annoying because they don't understand that what they're fearing cannot happen.

Comment: True - I was thinking of local variables, but it is not possible in general for the compiler to detect if a global pointer with external linkage has been initialised, because it is accessible from anywhere.

Comment: @JohnD: even just with locals it's impossible for a compiler to detect if in all **possible** code path a variable being used has been initialized or not before. What can be done is detecting in all **formally possible** code paths this happens (i.e. without accounting what will really happen at runtime), but this generates false positive (warnings on code that will never use an un-initialized variable). A compiler able to detect that without false positives could be used as an oracle very interesting questions (e.g. could be used to solve the Collatz conjecture).

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking if C++ can protect me from some errors, why not all errors? It can protect you from obvious mistakes, but it can't protect you from *every* mistake. However, as well as errors, it also gives a lot of warnings. In your example, I got a warning:

```
warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'p' used
```

The compiler can see that you haven't initialised `p` before you make the assignment.

Most places I worked at insist that all warnings are fixed before anything is released, which is a good policy - treat all warnings as errors!

Answer (score 0):

That thing is allowed because C++ doesn't track whether variables are initialized; your example has *nothing* to do with type safety (there is no incompatibility of types in there)